# Is the category of (pre)sheaves over a singleton isomorphic to the category of sets?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

I'm wondering whether $\mathsf{PSh}(\{x\})$ or $\mathsf{Sh}(\{x\})$ are equivalent to the category of sets. For sheaves, since the value on an initial object is a terminal object, It seems like the only degree of freedom except choice of singleton is the value on $\{x\}$. Still though, I'm not sure whether I'm not talking nonsense.

For presheaves, I really don't know at all..

Comment: Yes, sheaves of sets on a point are equivalent to sets. For presheaves, well, that depends on what you mean...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if $\mathcal{C}$ is any category with a terminal object $1$, then $\mathsf{Sh}(\{x\},\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C}$, $F \mapsto F(\{x\})$ is an isomorphism of categories.

On the other hand, there is an isomorphism of categories $\mathsf{PSh}(\{x\},\mathcal{C}) \to \mathsf{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ which maps $F$ to the restriction morphism $F(\{x\}) \to F(\emptyset)$.

By the way, under these isomorphisms, the forgetful functor from sheaves to presheaves becomes $\mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$, $X \mapsto (X \to 1)$, and its left adjoint (sheafification) is simply $\mathsf{Mor}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C}$, $(X \to Y) \mapsto X$.

Comment: The reason I ask is that I'm trying to show that taking a stalk of a presheaf is a special case of the presheaf-inverse-image defined by $U\mapsto \varinjlim _{V\supset f(U)}PV$. The codomain of the stalk functor is $\mathsf{Set}$ though, not $\mathsf{PSh}(\{x\})$. So what do I do in the case of presheaves?

Comment: In the end, evaluate at $\{x\}$.